How to prove the quotient of long exact sequences is a long exact sequence?
Let $f^{\cdot}: A^{\cdot}\to B^{\cdot}$ be an injective morphism of two long exact sequences of an abelian category. Then by taking cokernel, naturely we will have a new complex $K^{^{\cdot}}$. I want to show that this complex is a long exact sequence. I have proved it by elements tracing if they are considered in the category of abelian groups. I guess it should be true in general, but how to prove by pure diagram tracing?

The long exact sequence associated* to $0 \to A \to B \to K \to 0$ yields
$$\cdots \to H_n(A) \to H_n(B) \to H_n(K) \to H_{n-1}(A) \to \cdots$$
Since $H_n(B)=0$ and $H_{n-1}(A)=0$, we conclude $H_n(K)=0$. That is, $K$ is exact.
*See e.g. here, Theorem 9.1.
